# How to display table after submit using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

## html part

this is my html part for the submit button.

```
<form method="post" action="testSales.php">
   <nav>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <div id="week1">
               <input type="submit" name="week" value="Weekly" onclick="javascript:myfunction();"/> 
            </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <div id="month1">
               <input type="submit" name="month" value="Monthly" onclick='javascript:myfunction(); '/> 
            </div>
        </li>
     </ul>
     <ul>
        <li>
           <div id="year1">
              <input type="submit" name="year" value="Yearly" onclick='javascript:myfunction(); '/> 
           </div> 
        </li>
     </ul>
  </nav>
```

## for the table html code part

This is the table part.

```
<table id="week1" class="table table-bordered" style="display:none"></table>
<table id="month1" class="table table-bordered" style="display:none">/table>
<table id="year1" class="table table-bordered" style="display:none"></table>
```

## javascript

This is my javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunction()
    {
        var value=document.getElementById("week1").value;
        if(value == week1)
        {
            document.getElementById('week1').style.display='block';
        }
    }
</script>
```

My table was cant display. How can I solve it?

Comment: `table` elements do not have a `value` attribute.  Use a proper input/form or something else that has a `value` attribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes

Comment: Change the id name on table or vice versa document doesn't know on which element value are you getting.

Comment: not really understand.. but thanks for reply @jmargolisvt

Answer (score 0):

```js
function fnc1(id){
document.getElementById(id).style.display ="block"

}
```

```css
table{

border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="fnc1('week-1')">Click Me to show table </div>

<table id="week-1" style="display:none">
<tr>
<td> table content </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

you must set id on input to get its value

and id is unique so you can use

```
 <div id="week-container">
 <input id="week1">
<table id="week1-table">
```

to work correctly

also you can pass  a value directly into the function

```
 <input onclick="javascript:myfunction('week1');">
```

and

```
function myfunction(tableid){

 document.getElementById(tableid).style.display='block';
//show table week 1
}
```

finally 
by clicking submit your page will navigated 
to avoid that 
use this code on form

```
<form onsubmit="preventNav(event)">

 function preventNav(event){
event.preventDefault()
}
```

Comment: After set the id and how can I apply in javascript?

Comment: click on run code snippet and  create code like that